# sap.m.Dialog Shows Duplicate ID Error on 2nd Open

Tags: dialog, fragment, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am opening a dialog after clicking a button and filling some info into it. When I open the dialog once again it displays the error:

```
 Error: adding element with duplicate id '__xmlview1--__item0'
```

Below is the code : 
(Edited : saving the create dialog instance everytime the dialog is created)

```
        onAddMovie: function() {
        var view = this.getView();
        var createDialog = view.byId("CreateDialog");

        var oDummyController = {
            // This is when I clicked the Submit button in dialog
            submitDialog: function() {
            view.byId("panel").setVisible(true);

            user = view.byId("movie_name").getValue();
            var label = view.byId("movieName");
            label.setText(user);

            screenDate=view.byId("screeningDate").getValue();
            var date = view.byId("__date");
            var dateObject = new Date(screenDate);
            var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "MMM dd,YYYY" }); 
            var dateFormatted = dateFormat.format(dateObject);
            date.setText(dateFormatted);


            rating=view.byId("langRating");
            var radioRating= view.byId("movieRating").getSelectedButton().getText();
            if(radioRating == "Universal")
           { radioRating='(U)'; }
            else if(radioRating == "Adult")
            {
                radioRating='(A)';
            }
            else
            {
                    radioRating='(U/A)';
            }


            rating=view.byId("langRating");
            rating.setText(radioRating);

                MessageToast.show(user);
                createDialog.close();
            },
            closeDialog: function() {
                createDialog.close();
            }
        };
        // This is when the dialog event is fired, things are fine here
        if (!createDialog) {
            createDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(view.getId(), "Admin.view.Dialog", oDummyController);
        }

          if (this._createDialog) {
       this._createDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(view.getId(), 
       "Admin.view.Dialog", oDummyController);
      }
        view.addDependent(createDialog);
        createDialog.open();
        if (!createDialog.isOpen()) {
            //do sth
        }
    }
```

fragment :

```
         <core:FragmentDefinition  xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
           xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">

                <Dialog  title="Input Movie Details" width="100%" 
          class="sapuiMediumMargin" confirm="handleClose" 
             close="handleClose">
                    <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
                    <l:content>
                        <Input width="100%" placeholder="Movie Name" id="movie_name"/>
                        <HBox alignItems="Center" renderType="Bare">
                            <Label text="Year of Release" width="50%"/>
                            <ActionSelect selectedItem="Element sap.ui.core.ListItem#__item0" selectedKey="item1" class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin" selectedItemId="__item0" id="yearOfRelease" width="50%">
                                <items>
                                    <core:ListItem text="2017" key="item1" id="__item0"/>
                                    <core:ListItem text="2016" key="item2" id="__item1"/>
                                    <core:ListItem text="2015" key="item3" id="__item2"/></items>
                            </ActionSelect>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox alignItems="Center" renderType="Bare">
                            <Label text="Date of Screening" width="50%"/>
                            <DatePicker class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin" width="50%" id="screeningDate"/>
                        </HBox>
                        <HBox alignItems="Center">
                            <Label text="Movie Rating"/>
                            <RadioButtonGroup width="100%" columns="3" selectedIndex="-1" id="movieRating">
                                <buttons>
                                    <RadioButton  groupName="__group0" text="Universal" id="__button0"/>
                                    <RadioButton groupName="__group0" text="Adult" id="__button1"/>
                                    <RadioButton groupName="__group0" text="U/A" id="__button2"/></buttons>
                            </RadioButtonGroup>
                        </HBox>
                                <HBox alignItems="Center" width="100%" renderType="Bare">
                            <Label text="Enable Booking" width="70%"/>
                        <CheckBox id="enableBooking" width="30%" textDirection="LTR"/>
                    </HBox>
                        <FlexBox alignItems="End" alignContent="Center" justifyContent="End" class="sapUiTinyMarginTop">


                            <SegmentedButton selectedButton="__button3" id="__button21">
                                    <buttons>
                                        <Button text="Submit" id="__submit" press="submitDialog"/>
                                        <Button text="Cancel" id="__button41" press="closeDialog"/></buttons>
                                </SegmentedButton>
                                    </FlexBox>
                        </l:content>
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
                </Dialog>

            </core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Please help as I am new to Javascript and SAPUI5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be creating the same dialog over and over again which causes the duplicate ID error.

Check if `var createDialog = view.byId("CreateDialog");` really returns your former dialog.

**Dialog Creation**

To make sure you could just save it in an instance variable:

```
if (this._createDialog) {
  this._createDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(view.getId(), "Admin.view.Dialog", oDummyController);
}
```

Another solution would be to re-create it every time and keep destroying it after every close:

```
<Dialog afterClose="onAfterClose">

onAfterClose: function(oEv) {
  oEv.getSoruce().destroy();
}
```

This is what I refer to as self-destruction :D

**ID Conflicts**

When creating your fragment with the views id prefix:

```
sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "my.Fragment", this);
```

You have to make sure to not have any ID conflicts between controls of your view and your fragment. Ids like your `__item0` are similar to auto-generated UI5 ids (`__[type][count]`). Omitting the ui5-internal prefix `__` should be sufficient in your example fragment.

If you have to use ids extensively as you do (you don't have to in most cases) you are probably better of using a separate ID for your fragment

```
sap.ui.xmlfragment("fragment", "my.Fragment", this);
```

and query with

```
sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("fragment", "controlId");
```

BR
Chris

Comment: Destroying dialogs everytime leads to ugly unwanted scrolling. Reusing a dialog is the way to go.

Comment: well, it depends 

Comment: As usual ;) But still, destroying has ugly unwanted side effects.

Comment: First method not working and I don't want to destroy the dialog.

Comment: @Swappy Any dynamic control creation you do from code? Which control is the id '__xmlview1--__item0' belonging to? A control from the view or the dialog? Maybe you can post the dialog code as well.

Comment: @Swappy Edited my answer.

Comment: @cschuff It is giving the error : Error: adding element with duplicate id '__xmlview1--moviename'  . I am unable to get it why it is showing this error. "moviename" is the id of my Input.

Comment: @Swappy You are creating the dialog twice in the code you posted.